# where to put the styles for target all the major email clients

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I am designing an email template but it is breaking in many major email clients. I have no idea where to put all my styles for it. Before, I learned that email templates only support table format and styles need to be given inline.

But I know technology evolves a lot and there should be a better solution for putting all the styles around. Below is the sample of my code which I want to use in my email template. I have added style in header in style tag but Gmail ignores them.
What's the solution?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="layout">
<div class="column narrow">
  <div class="spacing">
    <p>Herligheter hva penge, tærer innflytelse forderve hukommelse.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="column wide">
  <div class="spacing">
    <p>Lettsindigheten anstrengende røbe, overser rekk makroner, sengeliggende avbetaler klokt uskjønt fedre.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body,
.wrapper {
  background-color: #add8c7;
}
.layout {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
 }
.spacing {
  margin: 20px;
}
p {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

And media queries are only possible to add in style tag but Gmail ignores style tags given in the html template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, email clients are not evolving at the rate you're hoping for (there's really no standardization and there are a ton of players). The only way to ensure best support is adding styles inline and organizing code into tables, as you previously stated.

Luckily, there is a pretty helpful tool for inline styles at [inliner.cm](http://inliner.cm). All you do is enter the styles as above, along with the structure, and it will automate the inline styling.

Good luck! Emails are a nasty business.

Comment: That was a great tool. Thanks for your help.